# My vbscript gets flagged by antivirus?

Tags: vbscript, antivirus

The IT company I work for has requested me to make a script that would be able to download the needed files and store them, in a folder for a later install.

This is the code I used

```
    Set BS = CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")
 BS.type = 1
 BS.open
 BS.Write xHttp.ResponseBody
 BS.savetofile "putty.exe", 2 '//overwrite

     If objFileSys.FileExists("putty.exe") Then
    objFileSys.DeleteFile "putty.exe"
 BS.SaveToFile "putty.exe", 2
 Set objFile = objFso.GetFile("putty.exe") 

'* If the file doesn't exist, it will be downloaded here. 
Else 
 BS.SaveToFile "putty.exe", 2
 Set objFile = objFso.GetFile("putty.exe")
 End If
```

This code ^ has no issues, however, this code does:

```
Set BS = CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")
 BS.type = 1
 BS.open
 BS.Write xHttp.ResponseBody

' If the file does exist, it will be deleted and re-downloaded.
 If objFileSys.FileExists("" + strDirectory + "\putty.exe") Then
    objFileSys.DeleteFile "" + strDirectory + "\putty.exe"
 BS.SaveToFile "" + strDirectory + "\putty.exe", 2
 Set objFile = objFso.GetFile("" + strDirectory + "\putty.exe")  

' If the file doesn't exist, it will be downloaded here. 
Else 
 BS.SaveToFile "" + strDirectory + "\putty.exe", 2
 Set objFile = objFso.GetFile("" + strDirectory + "\putty.exe")
 End If
```

For some reason the antivirus (sophos) flags the second code, but I'm unsure why?

The first code as you can see will just download the file and save it to were the .vbs is, the issue with this the company did not like that. I tried to put the files in C: but you need admin rights, which means you need to login as admin (ugh).

So I made the script just put all the needed files into a temp folder, "strDirectory" goes to "C:\Users\NAME\AppData\Roaming\Work" the reason I did this was because then the script would collect the PC's username i.e. Bob and so it would go to "C:\Users\Bob\AppData\Roaming\Work" example: 
"C:\Users\"+ PC NAME+ "\AppData\Roaming\Work"

But again the antivirus flags and I'm not sure why?

Thanks!

PS This is not my script I found it here on stackoverflow, I have just edited it to fit my needs.

PSS I cannot upload the full code for company issues, but the error is in the download part.

Comment: What is the warning messages you get from Sophos? I had sophos antivirus before on my phone, and it told me everything I've installed was unsafe (false positives). Maybe it helps to whitelist the script so the virusscanner will not scan that file again

Comment: I don't know the answer to this because I have no idea how sophos is flagging, but maybe consider concatenating using the `&` operator instead `+` and see if that makes sophos happy. Perhaps it's trying to detect some numeric overflow issue or something where the addition causes a buffer overflow in memory...?

Comment: @C0dekid, I'm at home right now, regardless Kaspersky Internet Security flags it as "HEUR:Trojan-Downloader.Script.Generic" But does not flag the first script as anything!

Comment: @JNevill, I have tried this too, still same results sadly.

Comment: The only difference I can see is one saves to the same location while the other saves to arbitrary location. This behaviour is likely seen as hostile injection of an executable file on to the computer, which is why it's flagged, even if it's a false positive. The script probably works because it's within the confines of the executed script's location, which will be deemed less of a risk. If you need the executable to save anywhere other then from where the script is running your only option is to whitelist the script with the antivirus product, ideally through a centrally managed admin portal.

Answer (score 3):

The two scripts are similar but just a small change can make a big difference.

- The first is constricted to saving the executable file in the location where the script has been executed from.
- The second isn't constricted and can theoretically save the executable anywhere on the target machine *(dependent on local security, execution rights of the script etc.)*.

This is a potential red flag for AntiVirus Software packages and the likely cause of the second script being flagged. The only suggestion without removing the AntiVirus *(which I wouldn't recommend)* would be to whitelist the script if supported in the package.

Usually, in corporate networks, AntiVirus is handled centrally, so there is potentially a way of whitelisting the script from a central admin portal but you would need to speak to your IT Infrastructure Team to facilitate it.

Answer (score 0):

Probably I know the reason why the antivirus flagged this, because it downloads a file, if an antivirus sees a file that downloads a file it triggers. I experienced almost the exact same problem while coding my computer voice assistant, this assistant can search on internet what you type and open the file in you want to open, and the antivirus has detected it, probably because it does the action I mentioned before.